# c#-taking specific needing text in filestream

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, filestream, txtextcontrol

I am doing log-in panel in c# form application.
I do not want use database.
I should take userID and password from txt file...

For example, the txt file has 5 user ID and 5 password. How can I take needing userID and password from txt?

Comment: You should show the code you have tried...
You should not use a database to store passwords. Instead save to the registry and encrypt the data.

Comment: yes I have not problem about encrypt data..It's ok...only I want to learn take specific text with filestream.All example takes full file.

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps for reading from a file is covered in MSDN How-to guide [Read From a Text File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Something like following (assuming each line contains user name and password separated by space):

```
var usersAndPasswords = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\passwords.txt")
      .Select(s => s.Split())
      .Select(r => new {User = r[0], Password = r[1]);
```

Note: storing passwords in plain text is normally bad idea, but if you are building personal "read all my Facebook accounts" type of application it may be ok.

Comment: the MSDN example reading full text in file. I need read specific points like mypassword and my userID..

Comment: @akdrmrk - just add `Where` with your criteria to my sample... Also it may be better to read all file into a dictionary if you actually planning to use it as DB, otherwise all operations on file will be `O(file-length)` instead of `O(1)` for dictionary (could be fine for small files/infrequent usage).